# How can I list urlpatterns (endpoints) on Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

How can I see the current urlpatterns that "reverse" is looking in?

I'm calling reverse in a view with an argument that I think should work, but doesn't. Any way I can check what's there and why my pattern isn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration

Comment: Turn on DEBUG mode and look at the list of URLS in the debug output?

Answer (score 311):

If you want a list of all the urls in your project, first you need to install django-extensions

You can simply install using command.

```
pip install django-extensions
```

For more information related to package goto [django-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/)

After that, add `django_extensions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'django_extensions',
...
)
```

urls.py example:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from . import health_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_url_info', views.get_url_func),
    path('health', health_views.service_health_check),
    path('service-session/status', views.service_session_status)
]
```

And then, run any of the command in your terminal

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

or

```
./manage.py show_urls
```

Sample output example based on config urls.py:

```
/get_url_info             django_app.views.get_url_func
/health                   django_app.health_views.service_health_check
/service-session/status   django_app.views.service_session_status
```

For more information you can check the [documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Actually I was wrong, this feature is not provided by django after all.

Comment: All I get from that is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Comment: NB:  you have to add `django_extensions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` after installing

Answer (score 123):

Try this:

```
from django.urls import get_resolver
get_resolver().reverse_dict.keys()
```

Or if you're still on Django 1.*:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.keys()
```

Comment: this return the view functions, not the urls

Comment: To have it return the urls, do this instead: set(v[1] for k,v in get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.iteritems())

Comment: Or for python3: `set(v[1] for k,v in get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.items())`

Comment: [`django.core.urlresolvers` was removed in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0), replace the import line with `from django.urls import get_resolver`

Comment: this isn't working for me anymore, only gives back a small subset of the urls in my project

Answer (score 94):

## Django >= 2.0 solution

I tested the other answers in this post and they were either not working with Django 2.X, incomplete or too complex. Therefore, here is my take on this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import URLPattern, URLResolver

urlconf = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF, {}, {}, [''])

def list_urls(lis, acc=None):
    if acc is None:
        acc = []
    if not lis:
        return
    l = lis[0]
    if isinstance(l, URLPattern):
        yield acc + [str(l.pattern)]
    elif isinstance(l, URLResolver):
        yield from list_urls(l.url_patterns, acc + [str(l.pattern)])
    yield from list_urls(lis[1:], acc)

for p in list_urls(urlconf.urlpatterns):
    print(''.join(p))
```

This code prints all URLs, unlike some other solutions it will print the full path and not only the last node. e.g.:

```
admin/
admin/login/
admin/logout/
admin/password_change/
admin/password_change/done/
admin/jsi18n/
admin/r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/
admin/auth/group/
admin/auth/group/add/
admin/auth/group/autocomplete/
admin/auth/group/<path:object_id>/history/
admin/auth/group/<path:object_id>/delete/
admin/auth/group/<path:object_id>/change/
admin/auth/group/<path:object_id>/
admin/auth/user/<id>/password/
admin/auth/user/
... etc, etc
```

Comment: How can i do if want to get url and name of view ... Because me i want to get name of view and pattern like your result ... Please how ?

Comment: @NathanIngram The view is stored in the "callback" property of the URLPattern object, so you could change the `yield acc + [str(l.pattern)]` line to `yield acc + [str(l.pattern)], l.callback`. Keep in mind that it will return the view function itself and not a name

Comment: I get error: --->>>> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: @NathanIngram The "print(''.join(p))" won't work because it's now a list of tuples instead of a list of strings, try "print(''.join(p[0]))".

Comment: Awesome example of tail recurency :) BTW - if someone wants to get view class just change `yield acc + [str(l.pattern)]` to `yield [l.callback.view_class]`

Answer (score 29):

Django 1.11, Python 2.7.6

> cd to_your_django_project
>
> python manage.py shell

Then paste following code.

```
from django.conf.urls import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
from django.core import urlresolvers
urls = urlresolvers.get_resolver()

def if_none(value):
    if value:
        return value
    return ''

def print_urls(urls, parent_pattern=None):
    for url in urls.url_patterns:
        if isinstance(url, RegexURLResolver):
            print_urls(url, if_none(parent_pattern) + url.regex.pattern)
        elif isinstance(url, RegexURLPattern):
            print(if_none(parent_pattern) + url.regex.pattern)

print_urls(urls)
```

Sample output:

```
^django-admin/^$
^django-admin/^login/$
^django-admin/^logout/$
^django-admin/^password_change/$
^django-admin/^password_change/done/$
^django-admin/^jsi18n/$
^django-admin/^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^add/$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^(.+)/history/$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^(.+)/delete/$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^(.+)/change/$
^django-admin/^wagtailimages/image/^(.+)/$
...
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me, although I had to add `None` to the  line `urls = urlresolvers.get_resolver(None)`, and I did sometimes get 'None' at the start of some URLs.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a quick and dirty hack to just get the information you need without needing to modify any of your settings.

```
pip install django-extensions
python manage.py shell -c 'from django.core.management import call_command; from django_extensions.management.commands.show_urls import Command; call_command(Command())'
```

This is piggy backing off [@robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns/67534589#answer-8844834). While correct, I didn't want to have `django-extensions` as a dependency even if it was for just a second.

Comment: What's wrong with django-extensions as a dependency?

Comment: @AlxVallejo Absolutely nothing! It’s a great well-maintained-module, but if you’re using it every 5 months because you just need to list out your urls (my scenario).. my solution might just be your thing. If you rely on it on a day-to-day, by all means: install it!

Answer (score 24):

In Django 3.0, it's as easy as:

```py
>>> from django.urls import get_resolver
>>> print(get_resolver().url_patterns)
[<URLPattern '' [name='home']>, <URLPattern '/testing' [name='another_url']>]
```

To get the patterns for a particular app, you could use the following:

```py
from django.urls import get_resolver, URLPattern

def get_admin_patterns() -> List[URLPattern]:
    for pattern in get_resolver().url_patterns:
        if getattr(pattern, "app_name", "") == "admin":
            return pattern.urlconf_name
```

```py
>>> get_app_patterns()
[<URLPattern '' [name='index']>, <URLPattern 'login/' [name='login']>, <URLPattern 'logout/' [name='logout']>, <URLPattern 'password_change/' [name='password_change']>, <URLPattern 'password_change/done/' [name='password_change_done']>, <URLPattern 'autocomplete/' [name='autocomplete']>, <URLPattern 'jsi18n/' [name='jsi18n']>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, only prints one API URL: `[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'api/v1/'>, <URLPattern '^$'>, <URLPattern '^media/(?P<path>.*)$'>]`

Comment: That's nice, but is there a way to get inside, say, the admin URL patterns?

Comment: @Bobort I added an example solution to your question

Answer (score 17):

I am using the next command:

*(Python3 + Django 1.10)*

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from django.conf.urls import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
from django.core import urlresolvers


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):

        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):

        urls = urlresolvers.get_resolver()
        all_urls = list()

        def func_for_sorting(i):
            if i.name is None:
                i.name = ''
            return i.name

        def show_urls(urls):
            for url in urls.url_patterns:
                if isinstance(url, RegexURLResolver):
                    show_urls(url)
                elif isinstance(url, RegexURLPattern):
                    all_urls.append(url)
        show_urls(urls)

        all_urls.sort(key=func_for_sorting, reverse=False)

        print('-' * 100)
        for url in all_urls:
            print('| {0.regex.pattern:20} | {0.name:20} | {0.lookup_str:20} | {0.default_args} |'.format(url))
        print('-' * 100)
```

**Usage:**

```
./manage.py showurls
```

**Sample output:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^(.+)/$              |                      | django.views.generic.base.RedirectView | {} |
| ^static\/(?P<path>.*)$ |                      | django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve | {} |
| ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$ |                      | django.views.static.serve | {'document_root': '/home/wlysenko/.virtualenvs/programmerHelper/project/media'} |
| ^(?P<app_label>polls|snippets|questions)/$ | app_list             | apps.core.admin.AdminSite.app_index | {} |
| ^(?P<app_label>activity|articles|badges|books|comments|flavours|forum|marks|newsletters|notifications|opinions|polls|questions|replies|snippets|solutions|tags|testing|users|utilities|visits)/reports/$ | app_reports          | apps.core.admin.AdminSite.reports_view | {} |
| ^(?P<app_label>activity|articles|badges|books|comments|flavours|forum|marks|newsletters|notifications|opinions|polls|questions|replies|snippets|solutions|tags|testing|users|utilities|visits)/statistics/$ | app_statistics       | apps.core.admin.AdminSite.statistics_view | {} |
| articles/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$ | article              | apps.articles.views.ArticleDetailView | {} |
| book/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | book                 | apps.books.views.BookDetailView | {} |
| category/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | category             | apps.utilities.views.CategoryDetailView | {} |
| create/$             | create               | apps.users.views.UserDetailView | {} |
| delete/$             | delete               | apps.users.views.UserDetailView | {} |
| detail/(?P<email>\w+@[-_\w]+.\w+)/$ | detail               | apps.users.views.UserDetailView | {} |
| snippet/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | detail               | apps.snippets.views.SnippetDetailView | {} |
| (?P<contenttype_model_pk>\d+)/(?P<pks_separated_commas>[-,\w]*)/$ | export               | apps.export_import_models.views.ExportTemplateView | {} |
| download_preview/$   | export_preview_download | apps.export_import_models.views.ExportPreviewDownloadView | {} |
| ^$                   | import               | apps.export_import_models.views.ImportTemplateView | {} |
| result/$             | import_result        | apps.export_import_models.views.ImportResultTemplateView | {} |
| ^$                   | index                | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.index | {} |
| ^$                   | index                | apps.core.views.IndexView | {} |
| ^jsi18n/$            | javascript-catalog   | django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog | {'packages': ('your.app.package',)} |
| ^jsi18n/$            | jsi18n               | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.i18n_javascript | {} |
| level/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | level                | apps.users.views.UserDetailView | {} |
| ^login/$             | login                | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.login | {} |
| ^logout/$            | logout               | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.logout | {} |
| newsletter/(?P<slug>[_\w]+)/$ | newsletter           | apps.newsletters.views.NewsletterDetailView | {} |
| newsletters/$        | newsletters          | apps.newsletters.views.NewslettersListView | {} |
| notification/(?P<account_email>[-\w]+@[-\w]+.\w+)/$ | notification         | apps.notifications.views.NotificationDetailView | {} |
| ^password_change/$   | password_change      | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.password_change | {} |
| ^password_change/done/$ | password_change_done | django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.password_change_done | {} |
| ^image/(?P<height>\d+)x(?P<width>\d+)/$ | placeholder          | apps.core.views.PlaceholderView | {} |
| poll/(?P<pk>\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$ | poll                 | apps.polls.views.PollDetailView | {} |
| ^add/$               | polls_choice_add     | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.add_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/change/$       | polls_choice_change  | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.change_view | {} |
| ^$                   | polls_choice_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/delete/$       | polls_choice_delete  | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.delete_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/history/$      | polls_choice_history | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.history_view | {} |
| ^add/$               | polls_poll_add       | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.add_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/change/$       | polls_poll_change    | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.change_view | {} |
| ^$                   | polls_poll_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/delete/$       | polls_poll_delete    | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.delete_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/history/$      | polls_poll_history   | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.history_view | {} |
| ^$                   | polls_vote_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| publisher/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | publisher            | apps.books.views.PublisherDetailView | {} |
| question/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | question             | apps.questions.views.QuestionDetailView | {} |
| ^add/$               | questions_answer_add | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.add_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/change/$       | questions_answer_change | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.change_view | {} |
| ^$                   | questions_answer_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/delete/$       | questions_answer_delete | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.delete_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/history/$      | questions_answer_history | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.history_view | {} |
| ^add/$               | questions_question_add | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.add_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/change/$       | questions_question_change | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.change_view | {} |
| ^$                   | questions_question_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/delete/$       | questions_question_delete | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.delete_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/history/$      | questions_question_history | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.history_view | {} |
| ^setlang/$           | set_language         | django.views.i18n.set_language | {} |
| ^add/$               | snippets_snippet_add | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.add_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/change/$       | snippets_snippet_change | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.change_view | {} |
| ^$                   | snippets_snippet_changelist | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/delete/$       | snippets_snippet_delete | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.delete_view | {} |
| ^(.+)/history/$      | snippets_snippet_history | django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.history_view | {} |
| solution/(?P<pk>\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | solution             | apps.solutions.views.SolutionDetailView | {} |
| suit/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$ | suit                 | apps.testing.views.SuitDetailView | {} |
| tag/(?P<name>[-_\w]+)/$ | tag                  | apps.tags.views.TagDetailView | {} |
| theme/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | theme                | apps.forum.views.SectionDetailView | {} |
| topic/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | topic                | apps.forum.views.TopicDetailView | {} |
| update/$             | update               | apps.users.views.UserDetailView | {} |
| ^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$ | view_on_site         | django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut | {} |
| writer/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$ | writer               | apps.books.views.WriterDetailView | {} |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Note that the docs recommend you don't use `print`.  Instead use `self.stdout.write`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: I needed to see/sort-by namespaces and also see all url parts, so extended this command in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42388839/179581

Comment: @Andrei, if you have a made an output  from your answer, it would give other users an ability to see a benefit of your method on me

Answer (score 16):

There is a recipe on [activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576974-show-all-url-patterns-in-django/)

```
import urls

def show_urls(urllist, depth=0):
    for entry in urllist:
        print("  " * depth, entry.regex.pattern)
        if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
            show_urls(entry.url_patterns, depth + 1)

show_urls(urls.url_patterns)
```

Comment: That last line should be `show_urls(urls.url_patterns)`.

Comment: I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urls'`, dont know why?

Comment: @Alexey This is something that probably has to do with django 2. Can you confirm this please so that I can update the answer?

Comment: I've placed this code in file `test.py` in the root of my project and has this error, also if i do `import urls` in interpreter then i also get this error.

Comment: It's not a Django 1 vs 2 issue: the `import urls` is a local import, so you probably need to do `from app_name import urls`.

Answer (score 10):

There's a plugin I use:  https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions, it has a show_urls command that could help.

Answer (score 9):

Simply type in a url you know does not exist and the server will return an error message with a list of url patterns.

For example, if you're running a site at http://localhost:8000/something

Type in

http://localhost:8000/something/blahNonsense, and your server will return the url search list and display it in the browser

Comment: Best and most practical answer

Comment: This is what I use, but I've encountered one limitation: it doesn't (not always?) expand included URL modules.

Answer (score 7):

```
def get_resolved_urls(url_patterns):
    url_patterns_resolved = []
    for entry in url_patterns:
        if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
            url_patterns_resolved += get_resolved_urls(
                entry.url_patterns)
        else:
            url_patterns_resolved.append(entry)
    return url_patterns_resolved
```

In python manage.py shell

```
import urls
get_resolved_urls(urls.urlpatterns)
```

Answer (score 6):

Minimalist solution for django 2.0

For instance, if you're looking for an url that's on the first app of installed_apps, you can access it like that:

```py
from django.urls import get_resolver
from pprint import pprint

pprint(
    get_resolver().url_patterns[0].url_patterns
)
```

Comment: Works for Django 1.* too if you import `get_resolver` from `django.core.urlresolvers`. Thanks Marcio!

Answer (score 4):

I have extended [Seti's command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504813/179581) to show namespace, all url parts, auto-adjust column widths, sorted by (namespace,name):
https://gist.github.com/andreif/263a3fa6e7c425297ffee09c25f66b20

```
import sys
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from django.conf.urls import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
from django.core import urlresolvers


def collect_urls(urls=None, namespace=None, prefix=None):
    if urls is None:
        urls = urlresolvers.get_resolver()
    _collected = []
    prefix = prefix or []
    for x in urls.url_patterns:
        if isinstance(x, RegexURLResolver):
            _collected += collect_urls(x, namespace=x.namespace or namespace,
                                       prefix=prefix + [x.regex.pattern])
        elif isinstance(x, RegexURLPattern):
            _collected.append({'namespace': namespace or '',
                               'name': x.name or '',
                               'pattern': prefix + [x.regex.pattern],
                               'lookup_str': x.lookup_str,
                               'default_args': dict(x.default_args)})
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(repr(x))
    return _collected


def show_urls():
    all_urls = collect_urls()
    all_urls.sort(key=lambda x: (x['namespace'], x['name']))

    max_lengths = {}
    for u in all_urls:
        for k in ['pattern', 'default_args']:
            u[k] = str(u[k])
        for k, v in list(u.items())[:-1]:
            # Skip app_list due to length (contains all app names)
            if (u['namespace'], u['name'], k) == \
                    ('admin', 'app_list', 'pattern'):
                continue
            max_lengths[k] = max(len(v), max_lengths.get(k, 0))

    for u in all_urls:
        sys.stdout.write(' | '.join(
            ('{:%d}' % max_lengths.get(k, len(v))).format(v)
            for k, v in u.items()) + '\n')


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        show_urls()
```

> **Note:** column order is kept in **Python 3.6** and one would need to use `OrderedDict` in older versions.

**Update:** A new version with OrderedDict now lives in django-s package: https://github.com/5monkeys/django-bananas/blob/master/bananas/management/commands/show_urls.py

Comment: from django.conf.urls import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver is not more valid in django > 2.0
But I adapted the gist and wroks fine now, thx

Comment: Faced this issue myself recently and updated the gist. One would need to use an earlier revision to run on Django < 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.8, Python 2.7+
Just run these commands in your Shell. Python manage.py shell and execute the following code.

```
from django.conf.urls import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
from django.core import urlresolvers
urls = urlresolvers.get_resolver(None)

def if_none(value):
    if value:
        return value
    return ''

def print_urls(urls, parent_pattern=None):
    for url in urls.url_patterns:
        if isinstance(url, RegexURLResolver):
            print_urls(url, if_none(parent_pattern) + url.regex.pattern)
        elif isinstance(url, RegexURLPattern):
            print(if_none(parent_pattern) + url.regex.pattern)

print_urls(urls)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your answer?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you have to run this in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

## Django >= 2.0 List Solution

adopted from @CesarCanassa

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import URLPattern, URLResolver

URLCONF = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF, {}, {}, [''])

def list_urls(patterns, path=None):
    """ recursive """
    if not path:
        path = []
    result = []
    for pattern in patterns:
        if isinstance(pattern, URLPattern):
            result.append(''.join(path) + str(pattern.pattern))
        elif isinstance(pattern, URLResolver):
            result += list_urls(pattern.url_patterns, path + [str(pattern.pattern)])
    return result
```

Comment: To get URLPattern name variable (this will give you reverse name eg name:name from path):
replace result.append(''.join(path) + str(pattern.pattern))
with result.append(str(pattern.name))

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocces

res = subprocess.run(
    'python manage.py show_urls',
    capture_output=True,
    shell=True,
)
url_list = [
    line.split('\t')[0]
    for line in res.stdout.decode().split('\n')
]
```

Comment: Can u explain it a little?

Comment: @FaisalNazik `subprocess.run()` allows you to run command line executables from python. You can pass the `show_urls` argument to manage.py, capture the output, which has to use the shell option (by default - as far as I know) and save it to the `res` variable. `url_list` is then a list... it uses a "generator" structure to generate each list item. Assuming that res outputs coded URLs with a `\t` character at the end of each one, we take a list item and split it then take the remainder (the first element), ie `[item for line in ...]`. `...` is needed to iterate over all URLs and read them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic import to gather all URL Patterns from each application in your project with a simple method like so:

```
def get_url_patterns():
    import importlib
    from django.apps import apps

    list_of_all_url_patterns = list()
    for name, app in apps.app_configs.items():
        # you have a directory structure where you should be able to build the correct path
        # my example shows that apps.[app_name].urls is where to look
        mod_to_import = f'apps.{name}.urls'
        try:
            urls = getattr(importlib.import_module(mod_to_import), "urlpatterns")
            list_of_all_url_patterns.extend(urls)
        except ImportError as ex:
            # is an app without urls
            pass

    return list_of_all_url_patterns
```

`list_of_all_url_patterns = get_url_patterns()`

I recently used something like this to create a template tag to show active navigation links.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.urls.resolvers import RegexPattern,RoutePattern
from your_main_app import urls

def get_urls():
    url_list = []
    for url in urls.urlpatterns:
        url_list.append(url.pattern._regex) if isinstance(url.pattern, RegexPattern) else url_list.append(url.pattern._route)

    return url_list
```

Here `your_main_app` is the app name where your settings.py file is placed

Answer (score 1):

Yet another adaption of @Cesar Canassa 's generator magic. This can be added to the `yourapp/management/commands/dumpurls.py` director of your **app** so that it'll be accessible as a subcommand in `management.py`.

*note:* I added a line to make sure it filters for only `yourapp`. Update or remove it accordingly if additional URLs are desired.

## As a `management.py` Subcommand

Deploy Path: `yourapp/management/commands/dumpurls.py`

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import URLPattern, URLResolver

def list_urls(lis, acc=None):

    if acc is None:
        acc = []
    if not lis:
        return
    l = lis[0]
    if isinstance(l, URLPattern):
        yield acc + [str(l.pattern),l.name]
    elif isinstance(l, URLResolver):
        yield from list_urls(l.url_patterns, acc + [str(l.pattern)])
    yield from list_urls(lis[1:], acc)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'List all URLs from the urlconf'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        urlconf = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF, {}, {}, [''])

        records, glen, nlen = [], 0, 0

        for p in list_urls(urlconf.urlpatterns):
            record = [''.join(p[:2]), p[2]]

            # Update me, or add an argument
            if record[0].startswith('yourapp'):

                clen = len(record[0])
                if clen > glen: glen = clen

                clen = len(record[1])
                if clen > nlen: nlen = clen
                
                records.append(record)


        self.stdout.write('{:-<{width}}'.format('',width=glen+nlen))
        self.stdout.write('{:<{glen}}Name'.format('Path',glen=glen+4))
        self.stdout.write('{:-<{width}}'.format('',width=glen+nlen))
        for record in records:
            self.stdout.write('{path:<{glen}}{name}'.format(path=record[0],
                name=record[1],
                glen=glen+4))
        self.stdout.write('{:-<{width}}'.format('',width=glen+nlen))
```

## Sample Output

```
(env) django@dev:myproj~> ./manage.py dumpurls
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path                                                                        Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yourapp/^api-key/$                                                          api-key-list
yourapp/^api-key\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$                                  api-key-list
yourapp/^attacks/$                                                          attack-list
yourapp/^attacks\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$                                  attack-list
yourapp/^attack-histories/$                                                 attackhistory-list
yourapp/^attack-histories\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$                         attackhistory-list
yourapp/^files/$                                                            file-list
yourapp/^files\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$                                    file-list
yourapp/^modules/$                                                          module-list
yourapp/^modules\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$                                  module-list
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I want to list api endpoints without having to basically rewrite my urlpatterns. You can't import urlpatterns into the view since it causes a circular import. So here is a pretty good solution using the `include` function from `django.urls`. This allows you to list any set of urlpatterns in the project.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.routers import APIRootView
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from django.urls import include
import re

# Create your views here.
class ApiRoot(APIRootView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = include('api.urls')[0].urlpatterns
        response = {}
        for url in urls:
            match = re.search(r'[\w\/\-]+', str(url.pattern))
            if not match:
                continue
            name = match.group()
            response[name] = request.build_absolute_uri(name)
        return Response(response)
```

[image]
Copy and paste this and fix up some stuff. Hacky solution that works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you can print all the URL patterns for a particular router by printing the urlpatterns from `router.get_urls()` (within your Django app's `urls.py` file).

Open your apps `urls.py` and add the print statement to the bottom of the file, so the whole file might look like this:

```
import pprint

from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"users", views.UserViewSet, basename="User")
router.register(r"auth", views.AuthenticationView, basename="Auth")
router.register(r"dummy", views.DummyViewSet, basename="Dummy")
router.register("surveys", views.SurveyViewSet, basename="survey")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]

pprint.pprint(router.get_urls())
```

The patterns are then printed like this:

```
[<URLPattern '^users/$' [name='User-list']>,
 <URLPattern '^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='User-list']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/admins/$' [name='User-admins']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/admins\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='User-admins']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/current/$' [name='User-current']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/current\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='User-current']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='User-detail']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='User-detail']>,
 <URLPattern '^auth/login/$' [name='Auth-login']>,
...
]
```