# Determine complete Django url configuration

Tags: django, url

Is there a way to get the **complete** django url configuration?

For example Django's debugging 404 page does not show included url configs, so this is not the complete configuration.

Comment: An answer should not be incorporated in the question but posted separately as an answer…

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Django is Python, so introspection is your friend.

In the shell, import `urls`. By looping through `urls.urlpatterns`, and drilling down through as many layers of included url configurations as possible, you can build the complete url configuration.

```
import urls
urls.urlpatterns
```

The list `urls.urlpatterns` contains `RegexURLPattern` and `RegexURLResolver` objects.

For a `RegexURLPattern` object `p` you can display the regular expression with

```
p.regex.pattern
```

For a `RegexURLResolver` object `q`, which represents an included url configuration, you can display the first part of the regular expression with

```
q.regex.pattern
```

Then use

```
q.url_patterns
```

which will return a further list of `RegexURLResolver` and `RegexURLPattern` objects.

Comment: Good idea! I made a simple script here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576974/

Comment: That's an elegant function. I started trying to write one, but it involved checking object types to see if they were `RegexURLPattern` or `RegexURLResolver`. Using `has_attr` is a much better idea. You should put your function in answer here on Stack Overflow. I'd upvote it.

Comment: this causes so much of cyclic import issues through settings file!!

Comment: This doesn't work. `import urls` causes exception: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urls'`

Answer (score 73):

Django extensions provides a utility to do this as a manage.py command.

```
pip install django-extensions
```

Then add `django_extensions` to your INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`. then from the console just type the following

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

Answer (score 7):

At the risk of adding a "me too" answer, I am posting a modified version of the above submitted script that gives you a view listing all the URLs in the project, somewhat prettified and sorted alphabetically, and the views that they call.  More of a developer tool than a production page.

```
def all_urls_view(request):
    from your_site.urls import urlpatterns #this import should be inside the function to avoid an import loop
    nice_urls = get_urls(urlpatterns) #build the list of urls recursively and then sort it alphabetically
    return render(request, "yourapp/links.html", {"links":nice_urls})

def get_urls(raw_urls, nice_urls=[], urlbase=''):
    '''Recursively builds a list of all the urls in the current project and the name of their associated view'''
    from operator import itemgetter
    for entry in raw_urls:
        fullurl = (urlbase + entry.regex.pattern).replace('^','')
        if entry.callback: #if it points to a view
            viewname = entry.callback.func_name
            nice_urls.append({"pattern": fullurl, 
                  "location": viewname})
        else: #if it points to another urlconf, recur!
            get_urls(entry.url_patterns, nice_urls, fullurl)
    nice_urls = sorted(nice_urls, key=itemgetter('pattern')) #sort alphabetically
    return nice_urls
```

and the template:

```
<ul>
{% for link in links %}
<li>
{{link.pattern}}   -----   {{link.location}}
</li>
{% endfor%}
</ul>
```

If you wanted to get real fancy you could render the list with input boxes for any of the regexes that take variables to pass to the view (again as a developer tool rather than production page).

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'regex'`

Answer (score 5):

This question is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem and I thought I would discuss my solution. A given Django project obviously needs a means of knowing about all its URLs and needs to be able to do a couple things:

1. map from a url -> view
2. map from a named url -> url (then 1 is used to get the view)
3. map from a view name -> url (then 1 is used to get the view)

Django accomplishes this mostly through an object called a `RegexURLResolver`.

1. RegexURLResolver.resolve (map from a url -> view)
2. RegexURLResolver.reverse

You can get your hands on one of these objects the following way:

```
from my_proj import urls
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
resolver = get_resolver(urls)
```

Then, you can simply print out your urls the following way:

```
for view, regexes in resolver.reverse_dict.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (view, regexes)
```

That said, Alasdair's solution is perfectly fine and has some advantages, as it prints out some what more nicely than this method. But knowing about and getting your hands on a `RegexURLResolver` object is something nice to know about, especially if you are interested in Django internals.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a complete list of registered URLs is to install [contrib.admindocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) then check the "Views" section. Very easy to set up, and also gives you fully browsable docs on all of your template tags, models, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted a package (django-showurls) that adds this functionality to any Django project, it's a simple new management command that integrates well with manage.py:

```
$ python manage.py showurls
^admin/
  ^$
    ^login/$
    ^logout/$
.. etc ..
```

You can install it through pip:

```
pip install django-showurls
```

And then add it to your installed apps in your Django project settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ..
    'django_showurls',
    ..
]
```

And you're ready to go.

More info here -
https://github.com/Niklas9/django-showurls

Comment: Nice, thank you. It might be useful if, next to each tree line, there was the name of the app defining the rule (or some similar way to detect the app).

Comment: Note that Django Extensions also includes a `show_urls` command - http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of all the urls in your project, first you need to install django-extensions

You can simply install using command.

```
pip install django-extensions
```

For more information related to package goto [django-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/)

After that, add `django_extensions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'django_extensions',
...
)
```

urls.py example:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from . import health_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_url_info', views.get_url_func),
    path('health', health_views.service_health_check),
    path('service-session/status', views.service_session_status)
]
```

And then, run any of the command in your terminal

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

or

```
./manage.py show_urls
```

Sample output example based on config urls.py:

```
/get_url_info             django_app.views.get_url_func
/health                   django_app.health_views.service_health_check
/service-session/status   django_app.views.service_session_status
```

For more information you can check the [documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the urls evaluated or not evaluated as shown in the DEBUG mode? For evaluated, django.contrib.sitemaps can help you there, otherwise it might involve some reverse engineering with Django's code.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the other answers here, I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

It looks like the problem comes from using `django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()` in my `urls.py`, so I can either comment that out, or load Django properly before dumping the URL's. Of course if I want to see the admin URL's in the mapping, I can't comment them out.

The way I found was to create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) that dumps the urls.

```
# install this file in mysite/myapp/management/commands/urldump.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from kive import urls


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Dumps all URL's."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.show_urls(urls.urlpatterns)

    def show_urls(self, urllist, depth=0):
        for entry in urllist:
            print ' '.join(("  " * depth, entry.regex.pattern,
                            entry.callback and entry.callback.__module__ or '',
                            entry.callback and entry.callback.func_name or ''))
            if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
                self.show_urls(entry.url_patterns, depth + 1)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are running Django in debug mode (have `DEBUG = True` in your settings) and then type a non-existent URL you will get an error page listing the complete URL configuration.

Comment: As I mentioned, this error page does not show the complete configuration because it does not include information about *included* url configurations.

Comment: I understood exactly what you meant about INCLUDED url configurations, but answered from faulty memory because I didn't have immediate access to a test site.  I swear I've see the URL error page put a space between the top level url and the included urls but see now it doesn't.  So the answer is NO, there is no way to see the complete configuration.

Comment: The error page shows only _relevant_ included url configurations. E.G. the 404 page for `/news/bad_url/` will display included urls from the `news` app, but not from the `sport` app.