# Django-grappelli admin: No reverse match error

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-grappelli

I've been working on a django project for a while now that uses grappelli for the admin and all of a sudden today my change_form.html template is throwing the following error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for "grp_related_lookup" with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The offending line of code is line 38:

```js
37    $.each(related_lookup_fields_fk, function() {
38        $("#id_" + this).grp_related_fk({lookup_url:"{% url grp_related_lookup %}"});
39    });
```

which is preceded by this bit of code:

```js
var related_lookup_fields_fk = {% get_related_lookup_fields_fk adminform.model_admin %};
```

Obviously it's the `{% url grp_related_lookup %}` bit that's causing the problem.

I don't understand how the template is resolving `grp_related_lookup` to `grappelli.views.related.related_lookup`. I have tried replacing `grp_related_lookup` with `grappelli.views.related.related_lookup` and that didn't work either. Also, in the template  the offending line looks like this:

```js
$("#id_" + this).grp_related_fk({lookup_url:"{% url grp_related_lookup %}"});
```

but in the error message it looks like this:

```js
$("#id_" + this).grp_related_fk({lookup_url:"{% url 'grp_related_lookup' %}"});
```

I don't know if the single quotes surrounding `grp_related_lookup` might have something to do with the problem or not. Is that how django rendered the function call? Is it passing the string `'grp_related_lookup'` to the url template tag? If so, what might have caused this to break *suddenly*?

Some additional info:

- The value of `related_lookup_fields` is an empty list `[]`. I am not defining any `related_lookup_fields` in my admin.py.
- I threw a couple debug statements into the `grappelli.views.related.related_lookup` view function and it doesn't appear to be getting called.
- I have not touched any of the templates recently.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction... Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you still have `'grappelli.urls'` included in your URLconf? That the only reason I see that would cause this error. You can try using `python manage.py shell`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
print reverse('grp_related_lookup')
```

If this line returns the correct URL, you shouldn't get a `NoReverseMatch` in your template.

The quotes around `grp_related_lookup` shouldn't be a concern. The `{% url %}` tag accepts both quoted and unquoted strings as first argument, so django normalizes it to quoted strings. This behaviour is going to change in the future: you'll be able to pass template variables to `{% url %}` using unquoted strings. `{% url foo %}` and `{% url "foo" %}` won't give the same result, see the [1.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) for details about this.

Comment: Yeah I have `( r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls') )` in my URLconf. I tried your suggestion in the shell and it's throwing an error also. Thanks for the heads up about the url template tag.

Comment: Interesting… Try printing all your URL patterns and see what it looks like? Using something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration

Comment: Thank you! Double checking my URL patterns was a good call. The grappelli url patterns are in fact missing. Now I need to figure out how and why...

Comment: Thought I'd follow up... the grappelli urls were actually included. I was mistaken yesterday. Anyway, banged my head against this issue for about a half hour this morning when it _magically_ fixed itself. Not feeling good about that, but it's _fixed_ so that's good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had a similar issue and turns out this was the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same behavior with Django 1.5 and Grappelli 2.4.4.

To fix the problem I had to **add**

```
url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
```

to `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this problem today, when I tried to delete data in admin.`Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found.`

I have put the `url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))` in urls.py

The solution is pretty strange: just update the grappelli to the latest version. (I updated it from 2.5.6 to 2.6.3)

Comment: Thank you for documenting this! I just had the same problem after I upgraded to Django 1.7.  My marketing team is busting down my door asking why the admin tool is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem yesterday. The Django-grapelli I used was the one that was included in the FileBrowser installation. I solved the problem by upgrading Django-grapelli. Just type:

```
pip install --upgrade django-grappelli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with urls and noticed that I need

```
{% load url from future %}
```

in the template if I want to have quoted url tags. That's also mentioned in the official django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be encountering this same issue, but when I run the suggested console test I get this:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  7 2015, 07:58:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> print reverse('grp_related_lookup')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tsantor/.virtualenvs/project_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 579, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/tsantor/.virtualenvs/project_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 496, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'grp_related_lookup' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

And my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(

    # Admin
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name="admin"),

    # main views
    #url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin'), name='home'),

    # API
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
)
```

I also have the latest Grappelli (2.6.4) running on Django (1.8.2). By the way, it seems it only occurs when I try to access and add or edit view.  The control panel and list views work.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
```

and fixed the problem.