# Django: Getting list of all URL regexes

Tags: python, django, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine complete Django url configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration)

I'm debugging a Django app, and I want to see the list of all URL regexes. I know I could look at the various `urls.py` files, but since they `include` each other, it's sometimes difficult to figure out the full urls just by looking at these files.

I want to see a list of *all* the URL regexes. How can I do that?