# reverse django url to object, not view. possible?

Tags: django

I have a set of URLs for which I would like to retrieve the django model associated with this url, not the django view which is what the [reverse URL Dispatcher does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse). The code would ideally look something like this:

```
urls_to_lookup = get_urls_to_lookup()
models = []
for url in urls_to_lookup:
    model = retrieve_django_model(url)
    models.append(model)
```

Since the urls I would like to lookup have unique models associated with them (via the [`@permalink` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator)), it seems like this is possible but my google skillz are coming up empty handed. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT** In case it helps brainstorming solutions, I'm pulling these URLs from Google Analytics for all blog posts and I want to dynamically display most frequently viewed pages. The URL itself is helpful, but I would like to grab the title, teaser, etc for each blog post for display and that is all stored in the database.

Comment: `@permalink` is really just a wrapper around `reverse`. It basically just means "take the return value of this method and feed it into `reverse`". It doesn't create some sort of registry of objects and their URLs.

Comment: yeah, but wouldn't that be nice [in the 0.00001% of times you need it like me :)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create a sitemap; there's the [sitemaps contrib app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sitemaps/).

If you are trying to print out all the URLs in a nice format, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration).

I'm trying to think of a reason for having such a feature, but it escapes me. However, this should do what you want (not tested):

```
from django.db import models

def retrieve_django_model(url):
    m_instances = [m for m in models.get_models() \
                     if m.objects.all().count()]
    for m in m_instances:
        if m.objects.all().order_by('?')[0].get_absolute_url() == url:
            return m
        else:
            return None
```

Since we can only fetch the absolute url from *instances* not models, the initial list comprehension filters out those models for which there are no instances, and hence we cannot get the absolute URL.

Comment: creating the mapping by hand definitely works. was hoping there was a better way to query the db directly or something

Comment: also, note edit above on the usage of this question. i thought i'd clarify in case it triggered some ideas for you. thanks for the input!