# How can you access all of the urls in urls.py from Django code?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine complete Django url configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration)

How can you access all of the urls in urls.py from Django code?

I want to get a list of all of the urls listed in `urls.py` and iterate through them in another Django view.

Answer (score 1):

See this related StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829565/654031). Also in the comments, someone posted [this fantastic script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576974/):

```
import urls

def show_urls(urllist, depth=0):
    for entry in urllist:
        print "  " * depth, entry.regex.pattern
        if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
            show_urls(entry.url_patterns, depth + 1)

show_urls(urls.urlpatterns)
```