# How to print all the Routes used in Django?

Tags: python, django, laravel, path

I want to display all the Routes in an app built with Django, something like what Laravel does with the command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Is there a way to get all the Routes?

Comment: if you are comfortable with the third-party app then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187/determine-complete-django-url-configuration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has command `show_urls`, sou after instalation you can do:

```
python manage.py show_urls
```