# how to get a list of all views in a django application?

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any way to get a list of all views in an django app? I have googled for answer. All answers shows a way to get list of urls.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1275601/192390) returns a list of _registered_ views.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Getting list of all the views of a Django project:**

To get all the views present in a Django project, we create a function `get_all_view_names()` which takes `urlpatterns` as input and  returns the complete list of views being used in the project as the output.

First, we import the `root_urlconf` module using `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`. Then `root_urlconf.urls.urlpatterns` will give us the list of project's urlpatterns.

The above urlpatterns list contains `RegexURLPattern` and `RegexURLResolver` objects. Accessing `.urlpatterns` on a `RegexURLResolver` will further give us a list of `RegexURLPattern` and `RegexURLResolver` objects.

**A `RegexURLPattern` object will give us the view name which we are interested in.** The `callback` attribute on it contains the callable view. When we pass either a string in our urls like `'foo_app.views.view_name'`  representing the path to a module and a view function name, or a callable view, then `callback` attribute is set to this. Further accessing `.func_name` will give us the view name.

We **call the function `get_all_view_names()` recursively** and add the view names obtained from a `RegexURLPattern` object to a global list `VIEW_NAMES`.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLResolver, RegexURLPattern

root_urlconf = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF) # import root_urlconf module
all_urlpatterns = root_urlconf.urls.urlpatterns # project's urlpatterns
VIEW_NAMES = [] # maintain a global list

def get_all_view_names(urlpatterns):
    global VIEW_NAMES
    for pattern in urlpatterns:
        if isinstance(pattern, RegexURLResolver):
            get_all_view_names(pattern.url_patterns) # call this function recursively
        elif isinstance(pattern, RegexURLPattern):
            view_name = pattern.callback.func_name # get the view name
            VIEW_NAMES.append(view_name) # add the view to the global list 
    return VIEW_NAMES

get_all_view_names(all_urlpatterns)
```

### **Getting list of all the views in a Django application:**

To get the list of all the views present in a Django application, we will use the `get_all_view_names()` function defined above.

We will first import all the `urlpatterns` of the application and pass this list to the `get_all_view_names()` function.

```
from my_app.urls import urlpatterns as my_app_urlpatterns # import urlpatterns of the app

my_app_views = get_all_view_names(my_app_urlpatterns) # call the function with app's urlpatterns as the argument
```

`my_app_views` gives us the list of all the views present in `my_app` Django app.

Answer (score 11):

Adding on to above fix by Rahul, if anyone is using ***Python3***, you will need to use `__name__` instead of `func_name`:

```
...
            view_name = pattern.callback.__name__
...
```

otherwise you will get the following:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_all_view_names'
```

(Thanks to [scipy-gitbot](https://github.com/scipy-gitbot) at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2101#issuecomment-17027406

As an alternative, if you are disinclined to using global variables, here is what I ended up using :

```
all_urlpatterns = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF).urls.urlpatterns
detail_views_list = []

def get_all_view_names(urlpatterns):
    for pattern in urlpatterns:
        if isinstance(pattern, RegexURLResolver):
            get_all_view_names(pattern.url_patterns)
        elif isinstance(pattern, RegexURLPattern):
            detail_views_list.append(pattern.callback.__name__)
get_all_view_names(all_urlpatterns)
all_views_list = []

# remove redundant entries and specific ones we don't care about
for each in detail_views_list:
    if each not in "serve add_view change_view changelist_view history_view delete_view RedirectView":
        if each not in all_views_list:
            all_views_list.append(each)
```

Then you can just iterate through `all_views_list` to get the list of filtered views.

### **update: Mar 1 2018**

In Django 2.0, `django.core.urlresolvers` is moved to `django.urls`. `RegexURLPattern` and `RegexURLResolver` are renamed to `URLPattern` and `URLResolver`. So you should use

```
from django.urls import URLResolver, URLPattern
```

instead of

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLResolver, RegexURLPattern
```

if you are using Django 2.

Comment: Here's updated code with both patches: https://pastebin.com/ALYJVgqE

Answer (score 3):

**Get all Django and DRF views w/o using global vars**

```
    def get_all_views(urlpatterns, views=None):
        if views is None:
            views = {}
        for pattern in urlpatterns:
            if hasattr(pattern, 'url_patterns'):
                get_all_views(pattern.url_patterns, views=views)
            else:
                if hasattr(pattern.callback, 'cls'):
                    view = pattern.callback.cls
                elif hasattr(pattern.callback, 'view_class'):
                    view = pattern.callback.view_class
                else:
                    view = pattern.callback
                views[pattern.name] = view

        return views
```

Comment: instead of `views = views or {}` use `views = views if views is not None or {}`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to count the number of views that were local to my project. [Here's code that does that](https://pym.dev/p/28vqe/).

This differs from current answers because:

- It groups views by the view object rather than the view name (which could collide with other view names)
- Views that are under a `ModelAdmin` class are not included
- The `get_all_local_views` function returns only the views within the current directory (or under `settings.ROOT_DIR`) that aren't under a `venv` directory

```py
from importlib import import_module
import inspect
from pathlib import Path
import importlib.util

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin
from django.urls import URLResolver, URLPattern


def is_modeladmin_view(view):
    """Return True if the view is an admin view."""
    view = inspect.unwrap(view)  # In case this is a decorated view
    self = getattr(view, "__self__", None)
    return self is not None and isinstance(self, ModelAdmin)


def get_all_views(urlpatterns):
    """Given a URLconf, return a set of all view objects."""
    views = set()
    for pattern in urlpatterns:
        if hasattr(pattern, "url_patterns"):
            views |= get_all_views(pattern.url_patterns)
        else:
            if hasattr(pattern.callback, "cls"):
                view = pattern.callback.cls
            elif hasattr(pattern.callback, "view_class"):
                view = pattern.callback.view_class
            else:
                view = pattern.callback
            if not is_modeladmin_view(view):
                views.add(view)
    return views


def get_module_path(module_name):
    """Return the path for a given module name."""
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)
    if spec is None:
        raise ImportError(f"Module '{module_name}' not found")
    return Path(spec.origin).resolve()


def is_subpath(path, directory):
    """Return True if path is below directory and isn't within a "venv"."""
    try:
        path.relative_to(directory)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        # Return True if view isn't under a directory ending in "venv"
        return not any(p.endswith("venv") for p in path.parts)


def get_all_local_views():
    """Return a set of all local views in this project."""
    root_urlconf = import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
    all_urlpatterns = root_urlconf.urlpatterns
    try:
        root_directory = settings.ROOT_DIR
    except AttributeError:
        root_directory = Path.cwd()  # Assume we're in the root directory
    return {
        view
        for view in get_all_views(all_urlpatterns)
        if is_subpath(get_module_path(view.__module__), root_directory)
    }


all_views = get_all_local_views()
print("Number of local views:", len(all_views))
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works with modern Django. The rest refer to URL resolver classes that don't exist anymore.