# Django get list of Classes defined in controller of an application

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am creating django permissions based on django views rather than basic model based permissions. Hence I want to get the list of all the classes in a view. I tried the following:

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_app_config('my_app')
```

And also:

```
import sys, inspect
inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['my_app'], inspect.isclass)
```

But I didn't get classes object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of all classes within current module in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python)

Comment: *list of all the classes in a view* <= How do you define that?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong i tried that but it is not working

Comment: @dhke by view in mean views.py file i.e. controller of my app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a list of all views in a django application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933229/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-views-in-a-django-application)

Comment: Do you want to get all classes for a particular app (as per your question title) or just the classes found in a given app/views.py file?

Comment: @JamesAgnew only views.py ones.. I made the change in the title

Answer (score 0):

```
apps.get_app_config('my_app').get_models()
```

will return a list of all models declared in your application.

if you want to get all models including those in INSTALLED_APPS you can

```
appconfigs=apps.get_app_configs()
for appconfig in appconfigs:
    models = appconfig.get_models()
```