# getting all view functions in form choice field django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am wishing to get all the names of view functions inside a form choice field.

I found an article of doing that in console but it is not working in forms.

[The link to article is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933229/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-views-in-a-django-application)

I changed the code slightly to fill my needs. I created a file named `get_views_list.py` and tried to import `all_views_list`

```
from M2.settings import ROOT_URLCONF
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
all_urlpatterns = __import__(ROOT_URLCONF).urls.urlpatterns
detail_views_list = []
def get_all_view_names(urlpatterns):
for pattern in urlpatterns:
    if isinstance(pattern, RegexURLResolver):
        get_all_view_names(pattern.url_patterns)
    elif isinstance(pattern, RegexURLPattern):
        detail_views_list.append(pattern.callback.__name__)
get_all_view_names(all_urlpatterns)
all_views_list = []

# remove redundant entries and specific ones we don't care about
for each in detail_views_list:
    if each not in "serve add_view change_view changelist_view history_view delete_view RedirectView":
    if each not in all_views_list:
        all_views_list.append(each)
```

but this shows error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f93f019cb90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/M2/M2/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
url(r'^user/', include('UserAccessControl.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/M2/UserAccessControl/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
from .views import *
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/M2/UserAccessControl/views.py", line 13, in <module>
from get_views_list import all_views_list
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/M2/UserAccessControl/get_views_list.py", line 4, in <module>
all_urlpatterns = __import__(ROOT_URLCONF).urls.urlpatterns
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'
```