# Get list of active URLs, with names

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I am trying to link to the django admin in one of my templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin' %}">admin</a>
```

And I get:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'admin' with arguments '()'
>   and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Ok, fine; it is not called `admin` then. I am sorry I do not know that by heart. How is it called? Maybe I have namespaced it? How do I find this? Should I just google for that, go to the admin sources, ...? I will find it eventually, but ... Is there not an easier way? I am in debug mode!

Could I please get a list of all active URLs, with names?

Answer (score 1):

You can access admin panel directly:

```
<a href="/admin/">admin</a>
```

or, using `url` tag and namespace `admin`:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin panel</a>
```

And see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) for reversing admin urls.

**EDIT**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23874019/1418794) a snippet to see all active urls. See entire thread for other solutions.

Comment: Thanks. That solves this particular problem, but not the general problem "how to get list of active URLs". Is this possible?