# django-rest-framework list of links to endpoints

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using django-rest-framework, I need to create an endpoint that lists links to other endpoints.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'pepperonis', views.PepperoniViewSet, 'Pepperoni')
router.register(r'supremes', views.SupremeViewSet, 'Supreme')
router.register(r'some-unrelated-endpoint', views.UnrelatedViewSet, 'Unrelated')
```

These viewsets I'm interested in all inherit from the same class:

```
class Pizza(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pass

class PepperoniViewSet(Pizza):
    pass

class SupremeViewSet(Pizza):
    pass
```

I can get all the relevant viewsets from Pizza.__subclasses__().  How can I create an API endpoint that lists hyperlinks to only these endpoints?

I'll need the endpoint to return something like this:

```
[{"url": "http://example.com/api/pepperonis/"}, {"url": "http://example.com/api/supremes/"}
```

Comment: did you read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` in your Serializer to do this.

Example:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
tracks = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    view_name='track-detail'
)

class Meta:
    model = Album
    fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

It will give result like:

```
{
'album_name': 'Graceland',
'artist': 'Paul Simon',
'tracks': [
    'http://www.example.com/api/tracks/45/',
    'http://www.example.com/api/tracks/46/',
    'http://www.example.com/api/tracks/47/',
    ...
]
}
```

*References:*

[django-rest-framework HyperLinkRelatedField Documentation.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)

Answer (score -1):

Do you want this endpoint to be at the base of our API? If so, (I could be wrong), but I believe the default router will automatically create an endpoint at the root of your API that links to all your other endpoints.

Comment: The endpoint will need to be explicit.  I have flexibility with where I put the endpoint, but I'll need to also include things like the model's verbose name.