# Django 2.2.3 How get all urls patterns and all views name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I code app with Django == 2.2.3

By now i want to get all urls_patterns of all my project and associated view name.

How can i get something like this:

```
    urls_patterns_view_names_list = [
        ("view_name", "view_name: url_pattern"),
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
]
```

I have seen several topics to the question of url patterns but none correspond and do what I want. For the most part the answers are very old and obsessive for my case. That's why I reformulate my question: I want to have the urls patterns and for each url associated the name of his view: How can I do that with Django 2.2.3 on python 3.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : How can I see a list of urlpatterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns)

Comment: It not the same case ! Read before answer ... And your topic very very old and not correspond to wath i want to do .....

Comment: @NathanIngram If something is old it is not necessarily wrong. The elder people are the most wise ones sometimes.

Comment: Please how to use django-extension in views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly trivial, but I've written a module, https://github.com/valohai/django-urr, that has utilities for working and traversing Django URL resolvers.

If you end up using it, you can just use

```py
for entry in django_urr.extract_urls():
    print(vars(entry))
```

– see [here](https://github.com/valohai/django-urr/blob/ea02aec4c8cd32a8ddac96108463edfe326d132f/django_urr/extract.py#L15) for all of the contents of `entry`s.

Comment: But how to get view name ?

Comment: That'd be `entry.name`.

Comment: @NathanIngram If you're happy with this answer, please don't forget to upvote it and mark it correct.

Comment: thanks you have proposed me where i can found my answer ... Your app is great. But it not really wath i ask... Thanks my brother...

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this with [`django-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/):

`pip install django-extensions`

Then in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    ...
]
```

And finally in your command line:

`./manage.py show_urls`

---

This will result in exactly what you want. From the package docs:

> `show_urls`: Produce a tab-separated list of (url_pattern, view_function, name) tuples for a project.

Comment: @NathanIngram You can get the result that you want by using this method. It is up to you whether you would use it or not. *"I want to have the urls patterns and for each url associated the name of his view"*

Comment: That is an awesome extension!