# Extracting all the APIs paths/urls for Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We want to discover/extract a list of new APIs between two releases.

Is there a way to parse and extract a list of API URLs and HTTP-methods to have this list of new APIs when comparing release code branches?

Comment: did u tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for your requirement is [django-rest-swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 
it is just a pip package that you need to install and follow the instruction given in the link.