# 'django_extensions' 'show_urls' closes within a blink of a second

Tags: django, cmd, django-extensions

I use Django extensions as shown here: [Django : How can I see a list of urlpatterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns)

to get a list of exposed urls.

I'm on win 10.

Cmd.exe opens and closes immediatly.
With a highspeed cam i could figure out that whats written in the cmd.exe makes senes.

**How can I prevent cmd.exe from closing by auto.**

Comment: How exactly are you running the command? Did you run it from a shell (with the correct venv activated if relevant)?

Comment: inside terminal powershell, which was not the right way :-(

Answer (score 0):

I if run CMD in Vscode terminal or cmd.exe outside vscode it works, problem only occures when powershell in vscode evokes cmd after manage.py show_urls.

In Vscode

```
CMD 
Enter //changes powershell to CMD
manage.py show_urls
```