# How to access a list of all url names in django from model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I need to list all url names, but I can't find this item dynamically in django.

I was trying to list all urls with code but that's not working. Because I am calling that function in model file and in choices part and that returns an empty list.

This is my code I use to extract all url names:

```
def get_url_names():
    list_of_url_names = list()
    list_of_all_urls = list()
    for name, app in apps.app_configs.items():
        mod_to_import = f'{name}.urls'
        try:
            urls = getattr(importlib.import_module(mod_to_import), "urlpatterns")
            list_of_all_urls.extend(urls)
        except ImportError as ex:
            # is an app without urls
            pass

    for url in list_of_all_urls:
        list_of_url_names.append(url.name)

    return list_of_url_names
```

but this code does not run in model file, because of raise import error. in that model import this function and this function imports that package again and that is a circuit import. I can not use this func in model and i need to use it where `makemigration` command executes that before model file and save that data to database or a text file. that's not optimal and I don't know where should I use it?

How do I use this func:

```
class RelativeLink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Link Name')
    url = models.URLField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Link URl')
    page = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=get_url_names())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django : How can I see a list of urlpatterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns)

Comment: No. I updated this question.